# YouTube плеер и фиксированый блок

Tags: flash-player, html, youtube, css

Всем привет. Столкнулся с проблемой позиционирования. Имеется фиксированная панель прижатая к верху экрана (header). На сайте имеется видео-плееры Youtube. При скроле сайта, если видео попадает в тоже положение с панелью, то плеер оказывается с верху.

Что пробовал:
Задать панели: `z-index: 99999999;` - не помогло. `position: relative` - не помогло.

Появилась альтернативная мысль: Делать каждому видео превью. Превью работать будет ок, но все же есть недочеты.

Как можно решить такую проблему? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если плеер флешевый, нужно добавить `wmode="transparent"` к `<embed>`-объекту.

[Подробный ответ на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4385166/870505)

Вообще, порой быстрее поискать в гугле, чем задавать вопрос кому-то. Если вам дорого время, конечно. Этот ответ - третий по запросу "flash z-index". Так-то!

Comment: Все же, я искал в поисковиках, но сформулировать правильный запрос не смог. Во-первых, я использую <iframe> для плеера. Во-вторых, к вашим высказываниям: вы заботитесь о чужом времени, хотя, прямо сейчас, потратили в пустую несколько минут своей жизни. Парадокс, не правда ли?

Comment: Хоть и ваш ответ мне не помог - он не работает. Меня он натолкнул на решение: добавить в конце scr='...?wmode=opaque' и проблема решена. Благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

```
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
```

и дописать атрибут для

```
<embed wmode="opaque"></embed>
```

после этого z-index заработает